# Getting value of primitive boolean type of one JFrame form in another JFrame Form?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, chat, actionevent

I designed this sample chat app using java swing and java-google-text-to-speech-api which allows you to translate languages. What I am trying to implement in this demo program is on click of the choose button The Text of choose button must be updated to ENGLISH first and Then HINDI and set a flag variable i to 0 or 1 accordingly. And then using this value of i in server program I want to figure out that either hindi message should be displayed or english.But I am not able to Do it.Is there something wrong in the way I am Handling Events to Achieve this??? If Yes, Then please give the solution.

Also, another problem I am facing is once I send a msg from client to server, I cannot send more messages until i re-run the program.How Do i Solve this???

Please help in this regards, If you need more explanation then let me know....

Thanks :)

CLIENT.JAVA

```
package serverappdemo;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import com.gtranslate.Translator;
import com.gtranslate.Language;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    String ogmsg;

    public Client() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
        }catch(java.io.IOException e) {}
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            ogmsg = jTextField1.getText();
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()) ;
            dout.writeUTF(ogmsg);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jButton3.setText("Eng");
        callLang();
    }                                        

    public int callLang() {
        int i = 0;
        if(jButton3.getText().equals("Eng")) {
            i = 0;
        } else if(jButton3.getText().equals("Hin")) {
    //        jButton3.setText("Eng");
    //        Translator tr = Translator.getInstance();
    //        ogmsg = tr.translate(ogmsg, Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
              i = 1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

SERVER.JAVA

```
//I removed the editor folds that contained form design code.
package serverappdemo;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.gtranslate.Language; // API
import com.gtranslate.Translator; //API

public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream dis;
    Client c;
    String str;
    Translator tr = Translator.getInstance();
//    int i = c.callLang();

public Server() {
    this.c = new Client();
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        server();
    }catch(java.io.IOException e) {}
}                                        

public void server() throws java.io.IOException {
    ss = new ServerSocket(6666);
    s = ss.accept();
    readData();
    dis.close();
    s.close();
}

public void readData() throws IOException {
    dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    str = (String) dis.readUTF();

    if( c.callLang() == 1 ) {
        Translator tr = Translator.getInstance();
        str = tr.translate(str, Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
        jTextArea1.setText(str);
    } else if(c.callLang() == 0) {
        jTextArea1.setText(str);
    }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}                                        


public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Server().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: what exactly didn't work out for you ? was there an error ? if there was, can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: There are no errors, In all cases, it displays the message in english Language.The problem is That the Server program isn't recognizing that Eng has to be used or Hindi.

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple, use JcomboBoxes for selection of a language and pass that value to other form then set the preferred language. However, be sure to keep access modifier concept in mind while packaging your program.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Using a JComboBox for choosing a Language and then passing that selectionindex in the second frame by using an instance of that class :)